# Laravel dynamic rerouting

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys i have a little problem i need to solve and i cant seem to find a way to do so.
I have an app that need to use different databases dynamically according to which user uses it.  I thought that i would give each user an URL that contains hes unique alphanumeric id. So the URL would be something like ww.mydomain.com/app/1kh1h3as/

So i have 2 problems:

1. where should i put the database switch code. Is it better of in config file or should i use it in model classes so i have use of URI class to parse out the id?
2. how can i make the router understand that it needs to offset all the calls by one segment so it wont go looking for 1kh1h3as controller and ww.mydomain.com/app/1kh1h3as/users/all will launch all() method within Users controller?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, Laravel 3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this

   DB::connection('mysql')->config['database']='your_user_database_name';
2. Try

   Route::any('app/1kh1h3as/(:bundle)', function() {
                       return 'Welcome to the Admin bundle!';
               });